# Woocommerce order_review, checkout page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've run into a problem with the layout of the order_review.php and checkout.php page on mobile devices (less then 479px).
The order_review is split into two columns (one called product_name and the other product_total). I'm trying to setup the column width such that the product_name would have 80% of the width while the product_total 15% or so. 
Also, most of my products have variations and they are listed on those two pages as well (under the product_name column). Each variation has it's own  tags - which also aren't displayed properly, the text looks almost on top of each other and very messy.
I've tried the following css (max-width:479px):
    CSS Styling I suggest:
    #order_review.shop_table td,#order_review.shop_table th{width:50%;}
    dt.variation{float:right;}
    dt.variation{float:left;}

```
<tbody><tr class="checkout_table_item"> 
<td class="product-name">חזה עוף 
<strong class="product-quantity">&times; 2</strong>
<dl class="variation"><dt>צורת חיתוך:</dt><dd>חצאים</dd>
                      <dt>סוג שקילה:</dt><dd>משקל</dd>
                      <dt>כמות:</dt><dd>2.5</dd>
</dl>
</td> 
<td class="product-total"><span class="amount">&#8362;96</span>
</td> 
</tr> </tbody>
```

If anyone has suggestions or has experience with this issue please let me know.
This is a snippet of the code, I cannot offer you a link at this time as I put the site in maintenance mode. If you want more of the code or have to see the live link let me know again what you need. I'm pretty sure you'll have to see the live link to understand the layout.

Comment: Without seeing more code it would be fairly hard to be able to help you, but it sounds like you might need some padding.

Comment: <tbody><tr class="checkout_table_item">
         <td class="product-name">חזה עוף <strong class="product-quantity">&times; 2</strong><dl class="variation"><dt>צורת חיתוך:</dt><dd>חצאים</dd><dt>סוג שקילה:</dt><dd>משקל</dd><dt>כמות:</dt><dd>2.5</dd></dl></td>
         <td class="product-total"><span class="amount">&#8362;96</span></td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>

Comment: I meant for you to edit the code into your post or provide a link to the page (if possible)